# How to remove CakePHP 3 Association Model from Query Builder Data array?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

> My `Query` is look like -

```
$Fields = ['MyModel.a','MyModel.b','OtherModel.c','OtherModel.d'];
$data = $this->MyModel->find('all')
  ->select($Fields)
  ->join([
    'OtherModel' => [
        'table' => 'other_model_table',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' =>[
            'MyModel.uniqueid'=>'OtherModel.uniqueid'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

> From above Query, `Output` is look like -

```
[
    'a' => 'some_value',
    'b' => 'some_value',
    'OtherModel' => [
        'c' => 'some_value',
        'd' => 'some_value'
    ]
]
```

> But my `Expected Output` is look like -

```
[
    'a' => 'some_value',
    'b' => 'some_value',
    'c' => 'some_value',
    'd' => 'some_value'
]
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use custom aliases for the fields of the other table:

```
$Fields = [
    'MyModel.a',
    'MyModel.b',
    'c' => 'OtherModel.c',
    'd' => 'OtherModel.d'
];
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**

Comment: I used like `$Fields = [
    'a'=>'MyModel.a',
    'b'=>'MyModel.b',
    'c' => 'OtherModel.c',
    'd' => 'OtherModel.d'
];` Because, there is too many joins (y)